# bing v6 kml import with bird's eye view

Tags: kml, bing-maps

I'm trying to implement Bing maps with Bird's eye view mode with a custom KML file.
I'm using Bing v6 because it has the KML import feature built-in but I'm having trouble with it.

Here's the example of my actual implementation:
http://alturl.com/w78mw [link broken]

The map loads the KML but it does not switch to bird's eye view as it was supposed to.

If I switch manually, I cannot zoom out for some reason, is this related with a bug of any kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**API reference:**

You can use the full prototype of the method `ImportShapeLayerData` to use the callback and set the style after you load the element, see the MSDN: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429606.aspx

You can use the property SetBestMapView (last parameter of the method) to set the view automaticaly or do it by your self.

**Example:**

And here is an example from your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bing Maps KML</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?
v=6.3"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;

        function GetMap() {
            map = new VEMap('myMap');
            map.SetCredentials("YOURKEY");

            map.LoadMap();
            map.SetMapMode(VEMapMode.Mode2D);

            map.SetZoomLevel(1);

            func_addGrid();

        }

        function func_addGrid() {
            var atlasGrid = new VEShapeLayer();
            var atlasShape = new VEShapeSourceSpecification(VEDataType.ImportXML,
                     "http://www.mediacode.pt/directions.kml", atlasGrid);
            map.ImportShapeLayerData(atlasShape, function () {
                map.SetMapStyle(VEMapStyle.Birdseye);
            }, true);
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
    <div id='myMap' style="position: relative; width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. I'm just having trouble adjusting bird's eye zoom. I've setup 'map.SetBirdseyeScene' method but it's not producing the desired results...

Comment: I've tried to control Bird's eye zoom but it's not working... can someone help me on this? Example url: http://alturl.com/qximg Thanks.

Comment: With Bird's eye view, you have two zoom levels. What you can do, based on your code, is to manipulate the map with the appropriate method called SetBirdseyeScene: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb877851.aspx. Explain what you're trying to do and I will update the answer.

Comment: I want it to zoom out in order to be able to see the route that i have defined in the custom KML file that I'm loading. On the example the zoom is too close...

Comment: As explained, the Bird's eye view is only available at the two closest zoom levels in v6.3 that's why you're too close. In v7 it is different but Bird's eye aerial imagery view still are only for the closest zoom, enhanced bird's eye view are available for higher zoom.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. What about v7 do i have more flexibility/options? Is there any code examples that enables me to use kml files in v7? Merci!

Comment: Currently, there is no KML module out there, you can get inspiration and write your own using the GeoRSS module from CodePlex: http://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/